# Node.js use installed package in public/javascripts file

Tags: node.js

I have installed a package using 'npm install package-name' and now I am wondering how I can use this package in my global.js file which is in the public/javascripts folder?

I have tried using 'var name = require('package-name');' in the global.js file however this does not seem to be working. Am I meant to reference the package some place else?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Posting some code, with any error messages would be useful.

Comment: Please look at my response for the below answer. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

So the short answer is use the [browserify](http://browserify.org/). Really understanding all the implications of sharing code between node and the browser is somewhat of a lengthy topic, so please take the time to read the tutorials and [the handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook). But the basic idea is

- in your `global.js` file, load the module from node with `var name = require("package-name");` as you are doing.
- Transform your file with browserify a la `browserify public/javascripts/global.js > public/javascripts/main.js`
- change your HTML `<script>` tag to load the new `main.js` file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have installed browserify and transformed my global.js to the main.js and changed the html script reference to the new main.js. However, I am getting the "Cannot find module kmeans" error. I have installed the package 'node-kmeans' and it is in my 'node_modules' folder and I am trying to reference the 'node-kmeans/lib/kmeans.js' file by using 'var kmeans = require('kmeans'). Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use require("node-kmeans"); the name you pass to require is the same name you passed to npm install

Comment: I have tried that as well but I am getting the same error "Cannot find module node-kmeans"